# Relationship between anti-commutators and correlation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, correlation-functions, observables, anticommutator

Ballentine (in his solution at the back of the book to his Problem 8.10) writes that
$$[Tr(\rho \{A,B\}/2)]^2$$
is related to the correlation between the observables represented by $A,B$, but gives no explanation as to why. I can see how (given the generalized to state operators Born rule)
something like
$$\langle AB \rangle = [Tr(\rho AB)]$$
would be related to the correlation between $AB$, but the symmetrizing action of the $A,B$ anti-commutator confuses me. Can someone explain quite generally the connection between anti-commutators and correlations between the two given observables (random variables)?

Comment: It might help if you mention the full title of the book and the edition in your question. Looking at "Quantum Mechanics - A Modern Development" by Lesley Ballentine, second edition, published in 2000, there is no anticommutator mentioned in that book, so I feel this is a wild goose chase.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the text. The anticommutator appears in Appendix D, in the solutions to the problems (solution to Problem 8.10 in particular). The one equation in that solution involves an anticommutator. @SuzuHirose

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with that book and that notation to answer your question but I find it surprising that you would ask like this without giving very much context. Good luck with getting an answer.